# Redefining a record's fields in Clojure

Tags: clojure

In The Joy of Clojure it states that:

> you can even redefine a record if desired to have different  fields
>   giving you the compiled performance of Java dynamically

Can someone clue me in to how this is done?

Thanks

Comment: @Kevin Page 191 - http://www.manning.com/fogus/Sample-Ch9.pdf :)

Comment: You mean how redefining a record is done ?

Comment: Yup, I don't know how to redefine a record and give it different fields.

Comment: Just use `defrecord` to define the record again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In chapter 9 we walk through the definition of the `FIXO` protocol and extensions to both a `TreeNode` record and `TreeNode` type.  We show that building up the implementation of `FIXO` can be done dynamically.  In fact, we start with a `TreeNode` record, extend the `FIXO` protocol and then define a `TreeNode` type and extend `FIXO` to it instead.  While we do not change the number of fields, we do change the type itself and once extended, all calls through the `FIXO` protocol resolve to the new type (we also had to redefine the `FIXO` extension to `nil` as it was returning the old record-based `NodeType`.

You'd likely not do this in code that you would deploy, but it's a useful technique when experimenting. Try to walk through the FIXO section and check the types as you go.